# Does firebase analytics provide full data export to BigQuery for all the newly added apps?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've added one app and linked it to BigQuery. Data export was working fine for a few months, after which I had to add a new app.

It appears that Firebase doesn't automatically link the new app for data export to BigQuery, despite mentioning in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export#enable-export) that all new apps would be automatically linked. It has been around 14+ days since the app was added and data started to appear in realtime section. I've manually linked the app in BigQuery integration for now but I'm not sure if I would get the old data or no.

**Question:**
Would the full old data from where the newly added app started streaming to Firebase Analytics be exported for BigQuery?

[image: BigQuery Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery export is not retroactive. Analytics data will only start to be exported in BigQuery from the day of linking. The historical data will not be included. You may consider exporting reports from your Google Analytics dashboard by following this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317657?hl=en), but the limitation here is that you can only export up to 5k rows when you download a report as a CSV.